# I need help to find the maximum common value from three arrays in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, computer-science, hardware

I am new to MIPS. I am trying to do this question where I have to find the greatest common prime factor from three integers. I got the prime factors from each of them and stored each of the prime factors in individual arrays. Now, I want to get the greatest common value from the three arrays. I don't know how to get the greatest common value from the three arrays.
Here is the code I have so far:

```
.data
    q:  .asciiz "Enter a number to factor: "
    r:  .asciiz "The prime factorization of "
    r2: .asciiz " is "
    comma:  .asciiz ", "
    n1: .asciiz ".\n"
    space: .asciiz " "
    arr1: .space 64 #array with 8 elements
    arr2: .space 64
    arr3: .space 64
.text

#used: $t0, $t1, $t2, $t3

main:   

    #should initialize array values to 1
    ###########
    # First Number
    ###########
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, q
    syscall

    li  $v0, 5
    syscall
    move    $t0, $v0 #the input

    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, r
    syscall
    
    li  $v0, 1
    move    $a0, $t0
    syscall

    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, r2
    syscall


    li  $t1, 2


    addi $t3, $zero, 0 #array index = 0

    while:  bge $t1, $t0, endWhile

        div $t0, $t1
        mfhi    $t2
        bnez    $t2, else #if n%2 == 0; else

        #$t1 has the value we need, should store $t1 in array
        sw $t1, arr1($t3)
        addi $t3, $t3, 4 #array index ++ 

        li  $v0, 1
        move    $a0, $t1
        syscall

        li  $v0, 4
        la $a0, comma
        syscall

        mflo    $t0

        j   while

    else:       addi    $t1, $t1, 1

            j   while
    endWhile:
        sw $t0, arr1($t3) #saving the last value $t0 in the array

        li  $v0, 1
        move    $a0, $t0
        syscall

        li  $v0, 4
        la  $a0, n1
        syscall

    
    

    ###########
    # Second Number
    ########### 
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, q
    syscall

    li  $v0, 5
    syscall
    move    $t0, $v0 #the input

    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, r
    syscall
    
    li  $v0, 1
    move    $a0, $t0
    syscall

    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, r2
    syscall


    li  $t1, 2

    addi $t3, $zero, 0 #array index=0

    while2: bge $t1, $t0, endWhile2

        div $t0, $t1
        mfhi    $t2
        bnez    $t2, else2 #if n%2 == 0; else

        #$t1 has the value we need, should store $t1 in array
        sw $t1, arr1($t3)
        addi $t3, $t3, 4 #array index ++

        li  $v0, 1
        move    $a0, $t1
        syscall

        li  $v0, 4
        la $a0, comma
        syscall

        mflo    $t0

        j   while2

    else2:      addi    $t1, $t1, 1

            j   while2
    endWhile2:
        sw $t0, arr1($t3) #saving the last value $t0 in the array

        li  $v0, 1
        move    $a0, $t0
        syscall

        li  $v0, 4
        la  $a0, n1
        syscall


 

    ###########
    # Third Number
    ###########
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, q
    syscall

    li  $v0, 5
    syscall
    move    $t0, $v0 #the input

    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, r
    syscall
    
    li  $v0, 1
    move    $a0, $t0
    syscall

    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, r2
    syscall


    li  $t1, 2

    addi $t3, $zero, 0 #array index=0

    while3: bge $t1, $t0, endWhile3

        div $t0, $t1
        mfhi    $t2
        bnez    $t2, else3 #if n%2 == 0; else

        #$t1 has the value we need, should store $t1 in array
        sw $t1, arr1($t3)
        addi $t3, $t3, 4 #array index ++

        li  $v0, 1
        move    $a0, $t1
        syscall

        li  $v0, 4
        la $a0, comma
        syscall

        mflo    $t0

        j   while3

    else3:      addi    $t1, $t1, 1

            j   while3
    endWhile3:
        sw $t0, arr1($t3) #saving the last value $t0 in the array
        
        li  $v0, 1
        move    $a0, $t0
        syscall

        li  $v0, 4
        la  $a0, n1
        syscall

    

    #at this point, the prime factors for each number are in their respective arrays

    
    ###########
    # End Program
    ###########
    li  $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: Try to work it out on paper, so you know what to do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.